# Update Picker Input, reuse selected data

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am constructing my first shiny app and I am facing some difficulty with a reactive input. In the menu visitors can select two input. First, they can select a year. Second, based on their year selection they can select a polygon. On the server side, I generate a reactive picker input so that the choices of polygon proposed to visitors react to the selected year. In the example data attached there is no polygon for year_3, so all choices in Select Polygon are disabled.

Based on the selected year/polygon combination I want to plot the relevant polygons on an OSM font. Polygons shape change between years. However here I am unable to find a way to plot the relevant polygon for each year/polygon selection. What I want is that when a visitor selects year_1, and both polygon_a and polygon_b, the app displays the shape of polygon_a and polygon_b for the year_1. Anyone can help here? Thank you!

I put together an example below:

First, UI and Server:

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(shinycssloaders)
  library(shinydashboard)  
  
  # Define UI -----------------------------------------------
  ui <- fluidPage(
    
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Polygons"),
    
    # Parameters
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
                    choices = c("2001" = "year_1", "2002" = "year_2", "2003" = "year_3")),
        pickerInput(
          inputId = "picker_cny",
          label = "Select Polygon",
          choices = paste0(unique(codebook$Polygon)),
          options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
          multiple = TRUE),
        width = 2),
      
      # Displat the reactive map
      mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("m"),
        tableOutput("table"),
        width = 10)
    ))
  
  
  
  
  
  # Define Server ------------------------------------------
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
    observeEvent(input$input_period, {
      
      codebook_mod <- codebook[codebook$Year == paste0(input$input_period), ]
      
      # Generate reactive picker input
      disabled_choices <- !codebook$Polygon %in% codebook_mod$Polygon
      updatePickerInput(session = session, 
                        inputId = "picker_cny",
                        choices = paste0(unique(codebook$Polygon)),
                        choicesOpt = list(
                          disabled = disabled_choices,
                          style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                         yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                         no = "")
                        ))
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    
    
    # Reactive df ----------------------------------
    reactive_codebook = reactive({
      filter = subset(codebook, Year == paste0(input$input_period))
      return(filter)
    })
    
    #shp <- left_join(shp@data, reactive_codebook(), by = "Polygon") # Should merge at some point to keep only polygons of the selected year
    
    input_cny <- reactive({
      paste0(input$picker_cny)
    })
    
    data <- reactive({
      shp[shp@data$Polygon %in% input_cny(),]
    })
    
    # Reactive Map ---------------------------------
    observeEvent(list(input$input_period, input$picker_cny),{ 
      
      output$m <- renderLeaflet({
        
        m <- leaflet() %>%
          # Add Basemap OSM
          addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
          addPolygons(data = data())
        
      })
      
      output$table <- renderTable(data())
      
    })
    
  }
  
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

Second, the data:

```
new("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", data = structure(list(id = c("2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1"), year = c("year_1", "year_2", "year_1", "year_2", 
"year_1"), poly = c("polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", 
"polygon_c")), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "data.frame"), 
    polygons = list(new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", 
        labpt = c(0.338510097570938, 47.8789367423025), area = 0.268213372645998, 
        hole = FALSE, ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(0.00681732104440386, 
        0.484029794150556, 0.770357278014247, 0.0545385683550191, 
        0.00681732104440386, 48.0457116592124, 48.1549787622059, 
        47.7394446143647, 47.6247016849114, 48.0457116592124), .Dim = c(5L, 
        2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(0.338510097570938, 
    47.8789367423025), ID = "1", area = 0.268213372645998), new("Polygons", 
        Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(1.80479134647667, 
        47.6955749862821), area = 0.224089549953543, hole = FALSE, 
            ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(2.17812991677432, 
            2.005834598087, 1.76305483084579, 1.38489920201411, 
            2.17812991677432, 48.0895910398079, 47.6353579269049, 
            47.3651675407816, 47.6314042027695, 48.0895910398079
            ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(1.80479134647667, 
        47.6955749862821), ID = "2", area = 0.224089549953543), 
        new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(2.10927583422516, 
        46.7882368725584), area = 0.559572966790018, hole = FALSE, 
            ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(2.31788915508705, 
            3.21777553294437, 1.79977275571466, 1.16576189858791, 
            2.31788915508705, 47.0193198894433, 46.8610635274769, 
            46.4774612519214, 46.8750461412294, 47.0193198894433
            ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(2.10927583422516, 
        46.7882368725584), ID = "3", area = 0.559572966790018), 
        new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(-0.181380225959222, 
        46.929122089418), area = 1.98990706779548, hole = FALSE, 
            ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(-0.760131296447621, 
            1.39414215357443, -0.310188107518964, -1.48276732715122, 
            -0.760131296447621, 47.4290593450155, 47.3921509322044, 
            46.131308065997, 46.8447458743678, 47.4290593450155
            ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(-0.181380225959222, 
        46.929122089418), ID = "4", area = 1.98990706779548), 
        new("Polygons", Polygons = list(new("Polygon", labpt = c(1.80479134647667, 
        47.6955749862821), area = 0.224089549953543, hole = FALSE, 
            ringDir = 1L, coords = structure(c(2.17812991677432, 
            2.005834598087, 1.76305483084579, 1.38489920201411, 
            2.17812991677432, 48.0895910398079, 47.6353579269049, 
            47.3651675407816, 47.6314042027695, 48.0895910398079
            ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L)))), plotOrder = 1L, labpt = c(1.80479134647667, 
        47.6955749862821), ID = "5", area = 0.224089549953543)), 
    plotOrder = c(4L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L), bbox = structure(c(-1.48276732715122, 
    46.131308065997, 3.21777553294437, 48.1549787622059), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", 
        projargs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
```

```
structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Polygon = c("polygon_a", 
"polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", 
"polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", 
"polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", 
"polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c"), Year = c("year_1", 
"year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", 
"year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", 
"year_2", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1"), Variable = c("Variable1", 
"Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", 
"Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", 
"Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", 
"Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4"), Value = c(1L, 
245L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 34L, 1L, 245L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 0L, 
34L, 0L, 34L, 90L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `disabled_choices` had all the rows, while the `choices` had unique Polygons.  The number of elements should be same in both.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

codebook <- structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                                 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Polygon = c("polygon_a",
                                                                                      "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a",
                                                                                      "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b",
                                                                                      "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b",
                                                                                      "polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c"), Year = c("year_1",
                                                                                                                                                    "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2",
                                                                                                                                                    "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2",
                                                                                                                                                    "year_2", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1"), Variable = c("Variable1",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4",
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4"), Value = c(1L,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   245L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 34L, 1L, 245L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 0L,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   34L, 0L, 34L, 90L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                -20L))

##########

# Define UI -----------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Colonial Concessions Within DRC"),

  # Parameters
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
                  choices = c("2001" = "year_1", "2002" = "year_2", "2003" = "year_3")),
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "picker_cny",
        label = "Select Polygon",
        choices = unique(codebook$Polygon),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE),
      width = 2),

    # Displat the reactive map
    mainPanel(
      #leafletOutput("m"),
      DTOutput("t1"),
      #tableOutput("table"),
      width = 10)
  ))

# Define Server ------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$t1 <- renderDT({
    ###  this will display all data when no Polygon is selected 
    # if (is.null(input$input_period)) myperiod <- unique(codebook$Year)  else myperiod <- input$input_period
    # if (is.null(input$picker_cny)) mypolygon <- unique(codebook$Polygon) else mypolygon <- input$picker_cny
    # code1 <- codebook[codebook$Year %in% myperiod & (codebook$Polygon %in% mypolygon),]
    
    ###  below code will display data only when at least one Polygon is selected; comment the line below and uncomment 3 lines above to display the other way
    code1 <- codebook[codebook$Year %in% input$input_period & (codebook$Polygon %in% input$picker_cny),]
    
    code1
  })

  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_period, {

    #codebook_mod <- codebook[codebook$Year == paste0(input$input_period), ]

    # Generate reactive picker input
    code1 <- codebook[codebook$Year %in% input$input_period,]
    codeu <- unique(codebook$Polygon)
    code1u <- unique(code1$Polygon)
    disabled_choices <- ifelse(codeu %in% code1u, 0,1)
    #print(disabled_choices)
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "picker_cny",
                      choices = unique(codebook$Polygon),
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      )
                      )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)



}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello YBS, thank for taking the time to answer my question. I am not sure the code you propose does what I am looking for. For example when I select year_1 and polygon_a the table shows all polygons for year_1 regardless of my selection of polygon_a... Also it be nice to show the shape files as well. Thank you!

Comment: Please note that in your sample dataframe, all 3 polygons are present for year_1.  Try year_2 and/or year_3.  The idea is to have the same number of elements in disabled_choices (with 1 or 0) as in choices.

Comment: What I mean is that when I select year_2 and then polygon_b I want the table to only show year_2 and polygon_b. At the moment when I select year_2 indeed I see polygon_a and polygon_b which are the two polygons for which there is data for year_2. But if I select polygon_b I want only data for polygon_b to be displayed.

Comment: it worked as planned. Thank you very much!