# Reactive Picker Input, Show Label

Tags: r, shiny

I am constructing my first shiny app for which I need to have a reactive picker input. Thanks to @YBS I succeeded in building this [reactive picker input][1].

However, in the picker input, instead of showing values I want to show labels. For example in the code below, instead of showing `year_1` I show the label `2001`. I want to do the same for `picker_cny`, instead of showing `codebook$Polygon`I want to show `codebook$Label` (i.e. instead of showing `polygon_a`I want to display in the picker input `Baron Dubois`).

I thought about writing `choices = paste(c(unique(codebook$Polygon), " = " unique(codebook$Label)),`

Any idea? Thank you!

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Polygon = c("polygon_a", 
"polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_a", 
"polygon_a", "polygon_a", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", 
"polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", "polygon_b", 
"polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c", "polygon_c"), Label = c("Baron Dubois", 
"Baron Dubois", "Baron Dubois", "Baron Dubois", "Baron Dubois", 
"Baron Dubois", "Baron Dubois", "Baron Dubois", "Baron Delasalle", 
"Baron Delasalle", "Baron Delasalle", "Baron Delasalle", "Baron Delasalle", 
"Baron Delasalle", "Baron Delasalle", "Baron Delasalle", "Baron Istog", 
"Baron Istog", "Baron Istog", "Baron Istog"), Year = c("year_1", 
"year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", 
"year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_2", "year_2", "year_2", 
"year_2", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1", "year_1"), Variable = c("Variable1", 
"Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", 
"Variable3", "Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", 
"Variable4", "Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4", 
"Variable1", "Variable2", "Variable3", "Variable4"), Value = c(1L, 
245L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 34L, 1L, 245L, 1L, 23L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 34L, 0L, 
34L, 0L, 34L, 90L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Here is the code:

```
# Creation of APP ------------------------------------------
remove(ui, server)

if (interactive()) {
  
  library(shiny)
  library(shinyWidgets)
  library(shinythemes)
  library(shinycssloaders)
  library(shinydashboard)  
  
##########

# Define UI -----------------------------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Colonial Concessions Within DRC"),
  
  # Parameters
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "input_period", label = "Period",
                  choices = c("2001" = "year_1", "2002" = "year_2", "2003" = "year_3")),
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "picker_cny",
        label = "Select Polygon",
        choices = unique(codebook$Polygon),
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE),
      width = 2),
    
    # Displat the reactive map
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("t1"),
      width = 10)
  ))

# Define Server ------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$t1 <- renderDT({
    # Display data only when one polygon is selected
    code1 <- codebook[codebook$Year == input$input_period & (codebook$Polygon %in% input$picker_cny),]
    
    code1
  })
  
  # Reactive pickerInput ---------------------------------
  observeEvent(input$input_period, {
    
    # Generate reactive picker input
    code1 <- codebook[codebook$Year %in% input$input_period,]
    codeu <- unique(codebook$Polygon)
    code1u <- unique(code1$Polygon)
    disabled_choices <- ifelse(codeu %in% code1u, 0,1)
    #print(disabled_choices)
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "picker_cny",
                      choices = unique(codebook$Polygon),
                      choicesOpt = list(
                        disabled = disabled_choices,
                        style = ifelse(disabled_choices,
                                       yes = "color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.5);",
                                       no = "")
                      )
    )
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
``

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68994999/update-picker-input-reuse-selected-data/68999463#68999463
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `name` attribute of the vector you use as the choices. Just globally define

```
choices_picker_cny <- unique(codebook$Polygon)
names(choices_picker_cny) <- unique(codebook$Label)
```

and then use this vector in the `choices` argument of your `pickerInput`, e.g.

```
pickerInput(
        inputId = "picker_cny",
        label = "Select Polygon",
        choices = choices_picker_cny,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
        multiple = TRUE),
      width = 2)
```